# Looking for a video about arithmetic disappearing in a few years

Tags: arithmetic

I saw a video 3 or 4 years ago.

The video is about the idea that arithmetic will disappear in the future and only will be a sport, like hunting that passed from a need to a sport.

In the video there was a little extract of interviews with three people (I think that one was Salman Khan from Khan academy) and it's about the actual model of education.

The video was posted [here](http://www.videoeneducacion.com/educacion/el-futuro-de-la-educacion-entrevista-con-tres-innovadores-de-la-educacion).

The video had Spanish subtitles, at [this address](https://www.scoop.it/t/aprendizaje-innovacion/p/4018407087/2014/03/26/aprendizaje-del-futuro-y-los-innovadores-de-la-educacion).

Could you help me in finding this video? Sorry there's so little info!

Comment: I don't know about the videos you want, but in case you are not familiar with Isaac Asimov's 1958 short story [*The Feeling of Power*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Feeling_of_Power) (freely available [here](http://urbigenous.net/library/power.html)), you'll want to read it. For what it's worth, I've been hearing and reading about the demise of arithmetic since calculators came out in the 1970s, and I've even read warnings by people like Augustus De Morgan in the mid 1800s about declining skills in numerical calculations.

Comment: I will add to the resources but in the positive. Conrad Wolfram brother of Stephen Wolfram, both part of the team behind Mathematica, has a Ted talk on the value of using computational tools to teach higher level reasoning at earlier ages. [Teaching Kids Real Math with Computers](https://www.ted.com/talks/conrad_wolfram_teaching_kids_real_math_with_computers) 
The idea is, the tools are there instead of watching skill erode with reliance on the tools, use the tools to build deeper understanding.

Comment: I work as a business consultant and find frequent need for doing "estimation math". Quick ratios or percentages or the like. Not just me, but my client senior executives as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Web Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20121226090036/http://www.videoeneducacion.com/educacion/el-futuro-de-la-educacion-entrevista-con-tres-innovadores-de-la-educacion), I was able to find on that page a link to a YouTube video (in English) called [Future Learning](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qC_T9ePzANg). It was posted in 2012 and the description says:

> Students are the future, but what's the future for students? To arm them with the relevant, timeless skills for our rapidly changing world, we need to revolutionize what it means to learn. Education innovators like Dr. Sugata Mitra, visiting professor at MIT; Sal Khan, founder of Khan Academy; and Dr. Catherine Lucey, Vice Dean of Education at UCSF, are redefining how we engage young minds for a creatively and technologically-advanced future. Which of these eduvators holds the key for unlocking the learning potential inside every student?